# Azure AD B2C Multiple Tenant Authentication

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-ad-b2c, .net-6.0

I've three different Azure AD B2C clients and I'm working on setting up a Multi-tenant Web API application. I know how to configure a single/multi tenant from a single B2C domain. But I need to validate the token which may come from three different tenants. the TenantId is a mandatory parameter for each request. So based on the TenantId I need to load the configuration(Instace,Domain,clientId) and validate the token. Please suggest me a design to do the same in .net6. Thanks in Advance.

I was thinking to create custom middleware similar like AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp and set up configuration based on tenantid. Then call the AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp with configuration. Not sure whether this is the preferred approach to proceed.

Comment: Why are you not using a single tenant?

Comment: Separate B2C is created for each customer as per health care data access policy. Its all in production now. We're in process now to create multi-tenant application without affecting the existing resources.

Comment: In general you seperate at the authZ layer, rather than at the authN layer. Data segregation would be at the authZ layer using attribute control. Separating identities into different tenants doesn’t seem necessary nor optimum with adequate authZ. You won’t really find a samples for your approach from MSFT due to this. If there is a specific regulation that says two account id’s cannot live in the same store (not about data access), then that would demand a separate tenant.

Comment: You could introduce a layer in between , check the tenant ID and redirect the authN request to the appropriate authN API[it could be a function in Azure function app].